# PhoneGap ondeviceready and geoPosition.getCurrentPosition will not work together

Tags: cordova

I have the following ondeviceready code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onDeviceReady() {
                getLocation();  
            }
```

If I just call getLocation(); without the event listener it works correctly (besides a double location services prompt).

However, if I call the getLocation(); in the code above it fails.  Specifically this function never returns anything and time's out: geoPosition.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, {timeout:7000});

What is the reason the code works outside the 'ondeviceready' but fails when I call it inside the code above?

Thoughts?

Here is my getLocation function:

`enter code here`

```
function getLocation(){

        var latitude = localStorage.getItem('Lat');
        var longitude = localStorage.getItem('Long');

        if (geoPosition.init()) {
            geoPosition.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, {timeout:7000});
        }

        function geoSuccess(p) {
            console.log("Found you at latitude " + p.coords.latitude + ", longitude " + p.coords.longitude);
        }

        function geoError() {
            console.log("Could not find you!");
        }
    }
```

EDITED - ADDED

You can see my code at: http://www.classhoppers.com/app/index.html

If you run the page above in Chrome it works. You can open the web inspector and see the local storage updates the Lat/Long

If you emulate an iPhone5 you will see the Lat/Long never updates.

Here is what I have found:

Calling my function: getLocation(); alone works

Calling it inside the OnDeviceReady doesn't work

First I check if it's a mobile browser then run the onDeviceReady.

```
if(SmartPhone.isAny() == true){ 
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
getLocation();  
}
}
else {
console.log('browser');
getLocation();
}
```

Here is a link to my getLocation() function: http://www.classhoppers.com/app/js/geoLocation.js

Comment: Have you tried un-nesting your functions? (like, move `geoSuccess` and `geoError` outside of `getLocation`) It looks like it could be a scoping issue

Comment: Thanks, I moved the functions but it had no effect.

Comment: When this function is called I should get a prompt to allow location services: geoPosition.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, {timeout:7000});

Comment: But that never happens.  Sorry for the multiple messages.  The enter key doesn't work in this text area

Answer (score 0):

Try manually inserting your script tag for cordova.js in the head of your index.html document. I suspect you are missing this script.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have that script loading before any others: view-source:http://www.classhoppers.com/app/index.html

Comment: Ok, I thought that might be the most likely problem. Cordova not being loaded and hence event not being fired. Have you run Chrome Debug tools on your cordova app to see if there are any console errors?

Comment: I edited the post.  Yes I have ran Chrome Dev Tools.  Here is what I found: If you run the code on this page in Chrome it works. http://www.classhoppers.com/app/index.html You can open the web inspector and see the local storage updates the Lat/Long

If you emulate an iPhone5 you will see the Lat/Long never updates.

Comment: @JeremyCallahan Have you checked that the `onDeviceReady` is being called in the mobile app.